# Firebase Cloud Functions Returning Processed Data Using onCall

Tags: typescript, firebase, google-cloud-functions

I've been using firebase cloud functions and have run into the issue where my functions sometime hang for up to 10 seconds before returning data. I have looked at the docs and it says that I should return a promise with my data once it is done. My structure is currently this:

```
export const SomeFnName = functions.https.onCall(async (params: SomeTypedParams, context: functions.https.CallableContext) =>
{
    // Bunch of validation that throw functions.https.HttpsError if there is one

    // load some data from the server
    const snapshot = await admin.firestore().collection(Collections.SOMEKEY).doc(params.SOMEID).get();

    // The the snapshot data
    const someData: FirebaseFirestore.DocumentData | undefined = snapshot.data();


    // Do some processing of above then return
    return {
       data1: someData["key1"],
       data2: someData["key2"]
    };
}
```

As you can see I am exporting the function from a separate file and then registering in like this

```
exports.SomeFnName = SomeFnName;
```

Is this the correct way to return processed data like this? If not what needs to be done for it to work? I can't see what else I would be doing wrong for the server calls to sometime take a long time to execute and sometimes fail outright.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're experiencing is typically called a "cold start".  It happens the first time a function is executed on a new server instance allocated by serverless backends such as Cloud Functions.  You're not doing anything wrong, you're just paying the cold start cost (plus any networking latency between your computer, Cloud Functions, and Cloud Firestore).

[Read about cold starts from Google search results.](https://www.google.com/search?client=firefox-b-1-d&q=cloud%20functions%20cold%20start)